# How do I access a variable that is inside a Class that is inside a List?

Tags: c#, class, arraylist

I am trying to learn to serialize XML files and I have hit a snag on accessing a variable that is inside a Class that is inside a List. Here is the declaration code:

```
public class Library{
    public string name;
    public List<Book> books;
}

public class Book{
    public string name;
}
```

Here is the code where I populate the List that I'm going to serialize, but whenever I run this code all of the `library.books.name` always end up being equal to the last thing I saved book as, in this case "Xenocide".

```
    public void MakeXML(){
        Library library = new Library();
        library.books = new List<Book>();       
        library.name = "Red";
        Book book = new Book();
        book.name = "Hobbit";
        library.books.Add(book);
        book.name = "Xenocide";
        library.books.Add(book);
    }
```

I was wondering if there is a way to acess the variable name inside the Class Book inside the List books, but I can't seem to find something. Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As simple as:

```
library.books[0].name
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, I don't know why I was dumb as to overlook it. I guess I'd just been staring at the problem for too long, thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

You've also got a problem where you're adding the SAME book to the library twice, and just changing its name inbetween. You need to create two separate book objects and add each one to the list.

```
    Book book1 = new Book();
    book1.name = "Hobbit";
    library.books.Add(book1);
    Book book2 = new Book()
    book2.name = "Xenocide";
    library.books.Add(book2);
```

Comment: I know I was using the same Book it's because eventually I want to rework this code to be as flexible as possible. I didn't want to have to create a new variable for each book in each list, and I didn't expect the list to update when I updated the variable(which was dumb on my part).

Comment: You can reuse the same variable *name* if you want, but you still have to call `new Book()` for each and every book you want to add. Remember, the list stores *references* to books, not copies of them.

Answer (score 0):

You have stumbled into what OOP is all about.  As DGH says, you are adding the same book to the list twice and just changing the name in between.

You are basically creating a new `Book` object called `book`:

```
Book book = new Book();
```

You are then assigning the name field of `book` to "Hobbit":

```
book.name = "Hobbit";
```

You then add `book` to your `Library.books` List field:

```
library.book.Add(book);
```

You then ***change*** then name field of your original book to "Xenocide" and add it to the list

```
book.name = "Xenocide";
```

This previous line is what I think you are forgetting.  `book` is a single object.  You can pass this specific *instance* of `Book` to any other class or method, and you are always working with the same `book`.  Most any change you make along the way always impacts the original book (there are some exceptions, but not many)

You need to create a new `Book` any time you want a different `Book`.  This is not optional, this is a requirement of any object orientated language.